# Получение информации из ячейки с гугл таблицы в телеграм бот

Tags: telegram, бот, google-spreadsheet

Помогите пожалуйста получить информацию с гугл таблицы: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VV22ct7O_NBqAAwMor2WMoV0Z6Xil-ER8QKd_B-_1DI/edit#gid=1481080409. Весь код находится в редакторе скриптов. Бот работает так:

1. Добро пожаловать в бот для расписаний! Выберите группу: 1 группа/2 группа/3 группа/4 группа.
2. Выберите день недели: Понедельник/Вторник ... Воскресенье.
   При нажатии на кнопку бот должен присылать информацию из нужной ячейки, но когда выбираешь день недели он почем-то ничего не выводит( Можете, пожалуйста, помочь?

Код:

```
var token = "1924578488:AAHFaKRwcEN6YH5aBxP7QH8eUxGg1vf5gmw";
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyVHA8BjsiWVOl8d__xqavQTu_kuD4Qlsj0VC4658TlWuosNs23/exec";

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

function sendMessage(id, text, keyBoard) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(id),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyBoard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}

function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); 
  var ssId = "1VV22ct7O_NBqAAwMor2WMoV0Z6Xil-ER8QKd_B-_1DI";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Лист1");
  var keyBoard2 = {
        "inline_keyboard" : [
          [{"text": "Понедельник",
            "callback_data": "monday"}],
          [{"text": "Вторник",
            "callback_data": "tuesday" }],
          [{"text": "Среда",
            "callback_data": "wednesday"}],
          [{"text": "Четверг",
            "callback_data": "thursday"}],
          [{"text": "Пятница",
            "callback_data": "friday" }],
          [{"text": "Суббота",
            "callback_data": "saturday"}],
          [{"text": "Воскресенье",
            "callback_data": "sunday"}]
         ]};
  
  if (contents.callback_query) {
    var id = contents.callback_query.from.id;
    var data = contents.callback_query.data;
   
         if (data == "first"){
           return sendMessage(id, "Выберите день недели.", keyBoard2);
           var data = contents.callback_query.data;
           if (data == "monday") {
             var first_monday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,1).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_monday)}  
           else if (data == "tuesday") {
             var first_tuesday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,2).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_tuesday)}
           else if (data == "wednesday") {
             var first_wednesday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,3).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_wednesday)}
           else if (data == "thursday") {
             var first_thursday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,4).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_thursday)}
           else if (data == "friday") {
             var first_friday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,5).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_friday)}
           else if (data == "wednesday") {
             var first_wednesday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,6).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_wednesday)}
           else if (data == "saturday") {
             var first_saturday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,7).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_saturday)} 
         
      } else if (data == "second") {
        var second = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(5,1).getValue();
        return sendMessage(id, second);
      } else if (data == "third") {
        var third = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(9,1).getValue();
        return sendMessage(id, third);
      } else if (data == "fourth") {
        var fourth = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(13,1).getValue();
        return sendMessage(id, fourth);
      }
    
  } else if (contents.message) {
      var id = contents.message.from.id;
      var text = contents.message.text;
      var keyBoard = {
        "inline_keyboard" : [
          [{"text": "1 группа",
            "callback_data": "first"}],
          [{"text": "2 группа",
            "callback_data": "second" }],
          [{"text": "3 группа",
            "callback_data": "third"}],
          [{"text": "4 группа",
            "callback_data": "fourth"}]
         ]};
      return sendMessage(id, "Добро пожаловать в бот расписаний! Выберите группу.", keyBoard);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `return` программа просто завершается, напишите ниже свой if с выбором monday т.е. это

```
if (data == "monday") {
             var first_monday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,1).getValue();
             return sendMessage(id, first_monday)
}
```

а это лишнее, оно уже выше написано: `var data = contents.callback_query.data;`

также в 21 строке можно указать так: `UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl + '/', data);` ибо у вас уже всё в нужной переменной имеется

не знаю программист вы или только начинаете раз не увидели такую ошибку, ниже в коде я ещё закоментировал некоторые строки знаками //, вот можете их убрать если они вам нужны будут строки эти и сделать дальше как вам нужно. Также можете попробовать всё гораздо грамотней оформить, разделить теже уровни и клавиатуры функциями чтоб выглядело ещё красиее, удачи :)

сам код вот

```
function doPost(e)
{
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); 
  var ssId = "ВАША ТАБЛИЦА";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Лист1");
  var keyBoard2 = {
        "inline_keyboard" : [
          [{"text": "Понедельник",
            "callback_data": "monday"}],
          [{"text": "Вторник",
            "callback_data": "tuesday"}],
          [{"text": "Среда",
            "callback_data": "wednesday"}],
          [{"text": "Четверг",
            "callback_data": "thursday"}],
          [{"text": "Пятница",
            "callback_data": "friday"}],
          [{"text": "Суббота",
            "callback_data": "saturday"}],
          [{"text": "Воскресенье",
            "callback_data": "sunday"}]
         ]};
  
  if (contents.callback_query)
  {
        var id = contents.callback_query.from.id;
        var data = contents.callback_query.data;
       
        if (data == "first")
        { //скорей всего после return программа завершается
           return sendMessage(id, "Выберите день недели.", keyBoard2);
                    
            
          // else if (data == "tuesday") {
        //   var first_tuesday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,2).getValue();
        //   return sendMessage(id, first_tuesday)}
        //   else if (data == "wednesday") {
        //   var first_wednesday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,3).getValue();
        //   return sendMessage(id, first_wednesday)}
        //   else if (data == "thursday") {
        //   var first_thursday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,4).getValue();
        //   return sendMessage(id, first_thursday)}
        //   else if (data == "friday") {
        //   var first_friday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,5).getValue();
        //   return sendMessage(id, first_friday)}
        //   else if (data == "wednesday") {
        //   var first_wednesday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,6).getValue();
        //   return sendMessage(id, first_wednesday)}
        //   else if (data == "saturday") {
        //   var first_saturday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,7).getValue();
        //   return sendMessage(id, first_saturday)} 
             
        } else if (data == "second")
        {
            //var second = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(5,1).getValue();
            //return sendMessage(id, second);
            var tt = "ahalai";
            return sendMessage(id, tt);
        } else if (data == "third")
        {
            var third = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(9,1).getValue();
            return sendMessage(id, third);
        } else if (data == "fourth")
        {
            var fourth = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(13,1).getValue();
            return sendMessage(id, fourth);
        }
        
                  
        if (data == "monday")
        {
         var first_monday = sheet.getDataRange().getCell(3,1).getValue();
         return sendMessage(id, first_monday);
        }  
    
  } else if (contents.message)
  {
      var id = contents.message.from.id;
      //не используется у вас нигде
      //var text = contents.message.text;

      var keyBoard = {
        "inline_keyboard" : [
          [{"text": "1 группа",
            "callback_data": "first"}],
          [{"text": "2 группа",
            "callback_data": "second"}],
          [{"text": "3 группа",
            "callback_data": "third"}],
          [{"text": "4 группа",
            "callback_data": "fourth"}]
         ]};
      return sendMessage(id, "Добро пожаловать в бот расписаний! Выберите группу.", keyBoard);
  } 
}
```